# Не получается переопределить свойство объекта

Tags: javascript

Хотела переопределить свойство numberFruits объекта fruits.

Подскажите, где ошибка в коде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var fruits = {};

Object.defineProperties(fruits, {
    "numberFruits":  {
        value: 1,
        configuration: true
    },
    "fruit": {
        get() {
            return this.numberFruits;
        },

        set(value) {
            if(value >= 0 && value <=3) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, "numberFruits", { value: value });
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        },
        enumerable: true
    }

});

alert(fruits.fruit);
fruits.fruit = 2;
alert(fruits.fruit);
```

Comment: Вы в сеттере пытаетесь переопределить свойство заново, а нужно просто его перезаписать.

Comment: По какой причине Вам не подошёл `this.numberFruits = {value}`?

Comment: @Klimenkomud, перезаписать это свойство, а если быть точным, изменить его значение с помощью оператора присваивания, невозможно. Т.к. при его определении ключ дескриптора данных `writable` получил значение `false`. Поэтому изменение значения свойства возможно только через `defineProperty`. Если ошибку из кода убрать, конечно. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У дескрипторов доступа и данных нет ключа `configuration`, а есть `configurable`.

В шестой строке, вы, как я понимаю, хотели описать свойство `numberFruits` как конфигурируемое, но использовали для этого не существующий ключ. А правильный ключ принял значение по умолчанию, которое не позволяет вам изменить свойство в будущем.

Замените в шестой строке `configuration` на `configurable`, и будет вам сачстье. )

P.S. Внимательно читайте документацию. Успехов вам.